# Read text file in a loop will not include the last line

Tags: bash, loops

My `somelist.txt` file contains something like:

```
a
b
c
```

Using the loop below will not return `c` in my `listing`. However if I press ENTER(new line) after the `c`, the loop will read it perfectly fine. Is there a way to make it read the last line without the need to have a new line after `c`?

`somelist.txt` that works:

```
a
b
c
(empty line)
```

Code:

```
while read list; do
listing="$list"
done <somelist.txt

echo $listing
```

Comment: i can't reproduce this. How are you checking it doesn't list `c` ? From your snippet, it isn't evident.

Comment: Edited the post. It's just echo the variable

Comment: Can you show what's the output when you run your code ?

Comment: The output would be `ab` only.

Comment: `while read list || [ -n "$list" ]; do ... <somelist.txt`  You are dealing with a file without a POSIX end-of-file (e.g. a `'\n'` at the end of the final line). Therefore you test whether `list` is non-empty. If it is, you have a final line without a `'\n'`.

Comment: This is very helpful. Could you post it as an answer so that I can close this?

Comment: Sure, glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with the possibility that the file you are reading does not contain a POSIX end-of-file. (meaning there is a chance it lacks a final `'\n'`), then the proper way to handle parsing the file is to add a check to your read statement to test whether `$list` was filled by your final read. For example:

```
while read -r list || [ -n "$list" ]; do
    echo "$list"
done <somefile.txt
```

You can use any test construct you like, the bash `[[ ... ]]` or good old `test -n "$list"` (which is equivalent to `[ ... ]`).

That way regardless of whether you have a POSIX eof, you will read all the lines. (most modern editors enforce a POSIX eof, but there are still plenty that don't)

Comment: Thanks again David. For other users out there, I used MacOS's TextEdit to produce the text file, as mentioned by David, it probably didn't enforce POSIX eof.

Comment: It is hit or miss on editors. `Vim` and `emacs` enforce a POSIX eof, `kwrite` doesn't, `nano` does. Some editors allow you to configure whether the check is done. I believe [geany](https://github.com/geany/geany/) does. Best policy is to add the check to cover all bases. (but once you know what you have on your system -- beware, human nature will take over and you will start slacking -- I'm no different `:)`

Comment: I'm no better too :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to emulate `cat`. See here, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

```
  while IFS= read -r list; 
  do   
    listing="$list"; 
  done < somelist.txt; 
  [[ -n "$listing" ]] && echo "$listing"
```

This will print: `c`.

To print all of them, use `echo` inside the `loop`.

```
  while IFS= read -r list; 
  do  
    echo "$list"; 
  done < somelist.txt; 
  [[ -n $list ]] && echo "$list"
```

Result:

```
 a
 b
 c
```

Comment: It still doesn't  print out the `c`. I think this have something to do with POSIX end-of file as mentioned by @David C. Rankin above

Comment: Yes, just try `while read list || [ -n "$list" ]; do echo "$list"; done <somefile.txt` That is the proper way of handling the non-POSIX eof.

Answer (score -2):

You are using "<" operator . So that It does not reach at last char. When it reach last .it break the loop. Just change the operation <  and use "="  . And Check it

Comment: "<" is not less than sign as in 1< n.  It actually reads the file as STDN "opens STDIN"